# How to remove white space under webpage

Tags: html, css, scroll

I'd like to disable scrolling on my webpage but when I'm on my homepage I can scroll a bit which reveals some white space. I don't know why this happens, can anyone help please? Thanks on advance.

*Note: You can see and try it when you click on 'Run'.*

```css
  @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One);

  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }

  body{
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    background: #2C3E50;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #4CA1AF, #2C3E50);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #4CA1AF, #2C3E50); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    
  }

  .container{
    margin: auto;
  }


  h1{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 60px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-shadow: #533d4a 1px 1px, #533d4a 2px 2px, #533d4a 3px 3px, #533d4a 4px 4px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 60px;
  }


  .title{
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
  }
  
  section {
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  .search {
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    background:rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
    border:0px solid #dbdbdb;
    border-radius: 7px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
  }

  .btnsearch {
    width: 50px;
    height: 31px;
    border-radius: 0px 7px 7px 0px;
    position:relative;
    border:2px solid #207cca;
    background-color:#207cca;
    color:#fafafa;
    left: -10px;
  }
  .btnsearch:hover  {
    background-color:#fafafa;
    color:#207cca;
  }


  .icon-div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
  }


.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
    transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
    transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 35px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    td {
        float: left;
        margin-right:10px;
        width: 45%;
    }
    td:nth-child(3) {
        clear: left;
    }
    .icon{
      width:100%!important;
      height:100%!important;
      margin-top: 50px;
    }
  }

  
  .icon:hover, .icon:focus, .icon:active {
    box-shadow: 0 50px 50px -50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 50);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }


  .icontext{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;

  }

  .contactbtn{
    margin-right: 15px;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 35px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 12px 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
    transition-property: box-shadow, transform;

    background: #007991;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #78ffd6, #007991);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #78ffd6, #007991); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  }

  .contactbtn:hover, .contactbtn:focus, .contactbtn:active {
    box-shadow: 0 50px 50px -50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 50);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
```

```html
<!--Title-->
          <section class="container">
          <h1>
            <br />
            <span class="title" >
               <label style="color:#e55643;">Burger</label><label style="color:#2b9f5e;">school</label>
            </span>
            <span class="title" style="color:#f1c83c;">afspraken</span>
          </h1>
        </section>

        <!--Zoekbalk-->
        <section id="zoekbalk" align="center">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Zoek iets op..." class="search"/>
            <input type="button" value="Zoek" class="btnsearch"/>
        </section>

        <!--Icoontjes-->
        <div style="text-align: center;">

          <div class="icon-div" style="display: inline-block;">
            <a href="afspraken.html">
              <img src="https://www.icloud.com/system/cloudos/17BHotfix5/cloudos_foundation/17BHotfix5/en-us/source/resources/images/app_icons/reminders_icon@2x.png" class="icon"/>
            </a>
            <span class="icontext">Afspraken</span>
          </div>

          <div class="icon-div">
            <img src="https://www.icloud.com/system/cloudos/17BHotfix5/cloudos_foundation/17BHotfix5/en-us/source/resources/images/app_icons/fmf_icon@2x.png" class="icon"/>
            <span class="icontext">Situaties</span>
          </div>

          <div class="icon-div">
            <img src="controlcenter.png" class="icon"/>
            <span class="icontext">Grenzen</span>
          </div>

          <div class="icon-div">
            <a href="../Categorie/Categorie.aspx"><img src="Multitaks.png" class="icon"/></a>
            <span class="icontext">Categoriëen</span>
          </div>

        </div>

        <!--Contact-->
        <div style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="button" value="contact" class="contactbtn"/>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin:0` to html and body.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin:0; /*Add this*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome @LucasVerhoest :-)

Answer (score 3):

Just add `margin: 0;` to `html, body` to avoid the default margin.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One);

  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0;
  }

  body{
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    background: #2C3E50;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #4CA1AF, #2C3E50);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #4CA1AF, #2C3E50); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    
  }

  .container{
    margin: auto;
  }


  h1{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 60px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-shadow: #533d4a 1px 1px, #533d4a 2px 2px, #533d4a 3px 3px, #533d4a 4px 4px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 60px;
  }


  .title{
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
  }
  
  section {
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  .search {
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    background:rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
    border:0px solid #dbdbdb;
    border-radius: 7px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
  }

  .btnsearch {
    width: 50px;
    height: 31px;
    border-radius: 0px 7px 7px 0px;
    position:relative;
    border:2px solid #207cca;
    background-color:#207cca;
    color:#fafafa;
    left: -10px;
  }
  .btnsearch:hover  {
    background-color:#fafafa;
    color:#207cca;
  }


  .icon-div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
  }


.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
    transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
    transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 35px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    td {
        float: left;
        margin-right:10px;
        width: 45%;
    }
    td:nth-child(3) {
        clear: left;
    }
    .icon{
      width:100%!important;
      height:100%!important;
      margin-top: 50px;
    }
  }

  
  .icon:hover, .icon:focus, .icon:active {
    box-shadow: 0 50px 50px -50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 50);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }


  .icontext{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;

  }

  .contactbtn{
    margin-right: 15px;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 35px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 12px 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
    transition-property: box-shadow, transform;

    background: #007991;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #78ffd6, #007991);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #78ffd6, #007991); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  }

  .contactbtn:hover, .contactbtn:focus, .contactbtn:active {
    box-shadow: 0 50px 50px -50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 50);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
```

```html
<!--Title-->
          <section class="container">
          <h1>
            <br />
            <span class="title" >
               <label style="color:#e55643;">Burger</label><label style="color:#2b9f5e;">school</label>
            </span>
            <span class="title" style="color:#f1c83c;">afspraken</span>
          </h1>
        </section>

        <!--Zoekbalk-->
        <section id="zoekbalk" align="center">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Zoek iets op..." class="search"/>
            <input type="button" value="Zoek" class="btnsearch"/>
        </section>

        <!--Icoontjes-->
        <div style="text-align: center;">

          <div class="icon-div" style="display: inline-block;">
            <a href="afspraken.html">
              <img src="https://www.icloud.com/system/cloudos/17BHotfix5/cloudos_foundation/17BHotfix5/en-us/source/resources/images/app_icons/reminders_icon@2x.png" class="icon"/>
            </a>
            <span class="icontext">Afspraken</span>
          </div>

          <div class="icon-div">
            <img src="https://www.icloud.com/system/cloudos/17BHotfix5/cloudos_foundation/17BHotfix5/en-us/source/resources/images/app_icons/fmf_icon@2x.png" class="icon"/>
            <span class="icontext">Situaties</span>
          </div>

          <div class="icon-div">
            <img src="controlcenter.png" class="icon"/>
            <span class="icontext">Grenzen</span>
          </div>

          <div class="icon-div">
            <a href="../Categorie/Categorie.aspx"><img src="Multitaks.png" class="icon"/></a>
            <span class="icontext">Categoriëen</span>
          </div>

        </div>

        <!--Contact-->
        <div style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="button" value="contact" class="contactbtn"/>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it!